# run PHP script from cli : php.ini memory_size not taken into account

Tags: php, magento, command-line-interface, memory-limit, reindex

I am trying to run a php script (magento reindexer script) from the command line. The script consumes a lot of memory so I am getting the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/karanta/www/karanta.fr/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 691`

To fix this issue, I edited the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file and set `memory_limit = 2048M`.

To check the configuration, I run a script containing `phpinfo();` from the cli and I see: `memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M`, so it seems the configuration is taken into account properly. `ini_get('memory_limit);` also returns 2048M.

However when I rerun the reindex script, I still get `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted` as if the memory_limit was still 512M. The script is unable to complete, I am out of ideas how to augment the memory_limit to allow the script to complete.

Edit: I also tried adding the instruction `ini_set("memory_limit", -1);` directly into the PHP script and it still hangs with the same `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted`.

Extra information:

Server is a dedicated machine at ovh running Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 with 64GB RAM!

`php -v` returns:

> PHP 5.6.12-1 (cli)  Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

`free -k -h` during script execution returns:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache     available
Mem:            62G        1,8G         48G         84M          12G         60G
Swap:          1,0G          0B        1,0G
```

`ps -aux` returns:

```
karanta  25568  5.6  0.0 229484 41824 pts/1    S    07:54   0:04 php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

---

Following @IgorGreg's recommandation, I tried setting the memory limit using Zend_Memory. I wrote this php script that I run from the cli in replacement of the shell/indexer.php script.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('admin');
umask(0);
$memoryManager = Zend_Memory::factory('none');
$memoryManager->setMemoryLimit(-1);
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(3);
$process->reindexAll();
?>
```

Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento in CLI mode parses the `.htaccess` file and if it finds a memory limit, or any other PHP settings there, applies them (yes, seriously....)

The responsible code is in `shell/abstract.php`:

```
/**
 * Parse .htaccess file and apply php settings to shell script
 *
 */
protected function _applyPhpVariables()
{
    $htaccess = $this->_getRootPath() . '.htaccess';
    if (file_exists($htaccess)) {
        // parse htaccess file
        $data = file_get_contents($htaccess);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_value\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
            }
        }
        preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_flag\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Solution

Do not set memory limit and execution time via `.htaccess`, use the `php.ini` or the virtual host configuration.

Comment: Awesome, the indexer script doesn't reach the memory limit anymore! However, the reindexation still doesn't complete successfully, it now gets stuck (process has cpu at 0%, nothing happens). I already tried killing the process and relauching the reindex script, same thing happens. I suspect a big MySQL query blocking the reindexation, is that possible? Any idea how to debug that?

Comment: after killing the process you should delete the lock files in `var/locks`. To monitor MySQL you can use the `mtop` tool or just `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

Comment: Yup, reindexing gets stuck because of queries such as `DELETE FROM 'core_url_rewrite' WHERE (url_rewrite_id IN('5498439', '5498441', '5498443', '5498445', ...` that time out. I already set `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to `1000` and that's still not enough! Would truncating the `core_url_rewrite` table fix this issue?

Comment: Probably, for a while. But don't do it if you have custom URL rewrites, they will be lost. The URL index of Magento CE is a big mess, more infos here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large

Answer (score 2):

In Linux systems, there can be three separate memory limit settings, one for the Apache DSO module php instance, one for the Command Line php instance and one for the cgi php instance.

Each installation will have its own php.ini file, for example `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and may have the ability to override the set memory_limit turned off (typically found in shared hosting).

The `php.ini` file for cli will need to have its memory_limit increased.

Another spot of trouble can occur if you are using the apc cache. It has to be enabled by adding the following to the apc config file.

```
apc.enable-cli=1
```

A third source of trouble if you are running under cPanel/WHM is that there can be several different versions of php installed due to the security restrictions put in place. I had to contact our hosting service provider to run that one down. Try using `which php` from the command line where you are having the failure and make sure it's the same version that's accessible via cron scripts. The php.ini file for that particular version also has to be set.

Comment: I am editing the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file as I start the php script from the command line. (also, I added some extra info at the bottom of the question)

Answer (score 0):

Setting memory_limit to -1 means no memory limit. However, if you set this value in php.ini or .htaccess it may be overwritten in run-time by the script.
To be sure it'll take effect, it's better to use `ini_set("memory_limit", -1);` in the script.
Generally, setting memory_limit to -1 in php.ini is not a good idea. It may cause your system to hang under certain circumstances.

Magento is built on Zend framework 1 which has its own memory manager. The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.memory.memory-manager.html)
says you may set the memory limit like so:

```
$memoryManager->setMemoryLimit(-1);
```

It doesn't need to be -1, it may be 1,073,741,824 , or any integer, in bytes.
I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I added `ini_set("memory_limit", -1);` to my php script and I'm still getting the `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted` error! How is that possible?

Comment: most probably the memory_limit setting is being overwritten somewhere after the added statement.

Comment: Tried it, still getting the same `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following step.

1 . change the following into .htaccess to your requirement
php_value memory_limit 256M =>  php_value memory_limit 2048M

2. Instead of reindexing all in one,do reindex one by one like

php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price

There is need to increase memory limit via .htaccess is because of you can see in abstract.php it will refer .htaccess configuration.

Let me know if you have still any query

Thanks